# VLCJ black screen (with sound) for some videos

Tags: video, vlcj

I have a problem with black screen (with sound) for some videos. The event "videoOutput" is never triggered for the non-working videos. It started yesterday after working for several months for all videos, and I've spent the last day examining the issue. Im starting to think it might be a bug within vlcj after examining the logs.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and VLC 2.2.0 and currently im running vlcj 3.0.1 but I've tried several different versions. All videos I test are mp4 and have been working before.

Below I have provided a code example together with the difference between the logs for a non-working and a working video.

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    //Get player
    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent m = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent(); 

    //Set gui components
    getContentPane().add(m);

    //Set JFrame settings
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.validate();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Play media
    m.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(configuration.getVideoURI());  

    //Enable overlay
    m.getMediaPlayer().enableOverlay(true);
```

It might not be important, but its that the ordering of the events that are different. The only thing that is different (regarding input and system) between the non-working and the working case is the two different videos, and I narrowed the video specs down to differ only on resolution if that can have any impact. Non-working: 854 x 480, Working: (480 x 338 and multiple others).

Part of log that differs:

```
Non-working:
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1958)                 | DEBUG | mediaChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer@1f966d18,media=native@0x7fc784090c30 (uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t@84098bf7),mrl=file:///home/erik/Videos/top10exp.mp4)
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1962)                 | DEBUG | Raising event for new media
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:704)                  | DEBUG | play()
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:314)          | DEBUG | onBeforePlay()
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:151)          | DEBUG | attachVideoSurface()
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:67)                   | DEBUG | attach()
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:70)                   | DEBUG | componentId=81788948
vlcj: (LinuxVideoSurfaceAdapter.java:39)             | DEBUG | attach(componentId=81788948)
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:72)                   | DEBUG | video surface attached
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:707)                  | DEBUG | after play
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:238)          | DEBUG | enableOverlay(enable=true)

Working:
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:704)                  | DEBUG | play()
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:314)          | DEBUG | onBeforePlay()
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:151)          | DEBUG | attachVideoSurface()
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:67)                   | DEBUG | attach()
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:70)                   | DEBUG | componentId=81788948
vlcj: (LinuxVideoSurfaceAdapter.java:39)             | DEBUG | attach(componentId=81788948)
vlcj: (CanvasVideoSurface.java:72)                   | DEBUG | video surface attached
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1958)                 | DEBUG | mediaChanged(mediaPlayer=uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer@33da7214,media=native@0x7f1c9c090b50 (uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_media_t@9c098a6c),mrl=file:///home/erik/Videos/summer1.mp4)
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1962)                 | DEBUG | Raising event for new media
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:707)                  | DEBUG | after play
vlcj: (DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:238)          | DEBUG | enableOverlay(enable=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

We got same problem with the black vlcj screen. Our problem is that after playing 2 videos the screen goes black and never comes again. But if we skip two videos then it is working. I run the same code on 3 different systems and on one system the code work's fine but it is not working fine for other systems.

The difference at one system and other systems is only Ram. So I think it is system resources problem. Just clear your all cached ram and then try. I hope it will work.

Try your same code on different systems and then see. Because I am thinking to see the system resources usage while playing vlcj.

I tried 800 x 600 Screen resolution and increase my ram then it's working smoothly.